# Ask location every time a download takes place

Tags: downloads

I am using ubuntu for almost a year now and I want to ask a small question here..
You may think that this is a stupid question but I am asking it here because I haven't got any solution for this problem..
I have installed **ubuntu 12.04** on my desktop.
My problem is whenever I download anything on my system(**I usually use firefox and transmission client for downloading purposes**) it automatically gets saved in "Download" folder but I don't like this mess.**I want my ubuntu to ask me for the location of download every time I download anything**, so that everything is in its proper place..But I don't know how to do this..**I don't want to use any download manager because it will create its own folders and will again mess up the things..**
So please help me out guys!!
Thanks in advanced!!

Answer (score 3):

If using Firefox alone, do the following:

- Go to Edit -> Preferences
- Click the "General" tab (top left of the preferences box)
- Look to the "Downloads" section at the bottom, and change the setting from "Save files to Downloads" to "Always ask me where to save files".
- Click "Close".

It should now give you a dialogue box every time you download something, asking where you want to save each file individually.

Comment: Thanks Jez W and RayofCommand and for your instant help! Thanks a lot!!                                                            And what should I do if I want to change this setting in ubuntu itself i.e. it should be independent of software I am using

Answer (score 0):

it's in the firefox settings.

EDIT -> Preferences -> General

Downloads 
either save files to a spec. location (default /Downloads)

or always ask me where to save files

see my screenshot

[image: Download Location]

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu **doesn't** ask for the location of downloads, **applications** do.

Firefox can be configured for ask where to save files, as pointed in [other](https://askubuntu.com/a/323886/65926) [answers](https://askubuntu.com/a/323883/65926).

Transmission only offers to select the folder where files will be saved to.
[image]

Comment: Okay! But then this means every time I download something(using a new application) I have to edit my preferences? Isn't there a way like writing a script or something like that?

Comment: @user2334787 Yes, you have to properly configure every new application you use to download something. I think automation isn't possible because there's no standard for application settings. Each programmer uses his own solution for settings storage.